# Two chords in a circle cut each other up into equal line segments. What's the radius of the circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, bisection

I may be remembering the question wrong. It went something like

> Two chords in a circle split each other up into equal line segments of 1 and 3, respectively. Find the radius of the circle.

which I interpret to be

> Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be chords in a circle. $C_1$ cuts up $C_2$ into equal line segments of length 3. $C_2$ cuts up $C_1$ into equal line segments of length 1. Find the radius of the circle.

What I tried:

If they're bisectors of each other, the longer one must pass through the center hence the radius is 3.

However I read

> In a circle, the perpendicular bisector of a chord passes through the center of the circle.

so radius is 1 as well?

Comment: Just imagining it is impossible. Maybe the chords cut each other 1:3. Now that's imaginable.

Comment: @Dante Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer the question mentioned in your title in the following way.

The only way that can let “two chords (of the same circle) cut each other up into (4) equal line segments” is:-

Those chords are the diameters of that circle and therefore the radius is half the length of any one of the chords.

I don't know why the question is eventually interpreted as "Two chords in a circle split each other up into equal line segments of 1 and 3, respectively."